# Regex how to match an optional character with condition

Tags: regex

I need a regex to let a String matches if it's empty or has a length between 8,16

I tried this one `" (.?|(\w){8,16})$ "` but it doesn't work.

Thank you

Comment: What you mean exactly by *empty*? and what would be the format of your string?

Comment: "It doesn't work" is about the worst way to describe an issue.

Comment: Regex: `^(.{8,16})?$`.

Comment: @Phylogenesis you need to put that inside a group.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Yeah. realised it would use `?` as a less-greedy operator instead of the conditional one.

Comment: The string has to match only when it has a length equals zero o between 8 and 16. the format is not important, it could be numbers or chars or mixed.

Comment: I get it : ^(?:\w{8,16})?$ thank you.
@I'L'I  you're right but thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want something like this,

```
^(?:.{8,16})?$
```

or

```
^(?:\w{8,16})?$
```

Comment: Accept an answer which helps you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job: `^(|.{8,16})$`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/cU9mK7/1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
    ((.){8,16})|(.{0})
Let me know if it helped.

Comment: ^(?:.{8,16})?$ i used this one for my job. thank you for your response

Answer (score 0):

Your regex `(.?|(\w){8,16})$` "doesn't work" because of how regexes work in general, there are multiple flaws. Between alternations the most-left one is tested first. `.?` means 0 or 1 times of any character (which also means that string with length of 1 is incorrectly matched as well). So, a 8 character string will match its last character because of `.?` and your second alternation isn't even checked.

Another thing is the usage of `$` and no `^`, this means that you will simply check the last 8-16 characters (if there are any). `^` is the start of the string and is needed to use here (to check whole string from start to finish).

`^(|\w{8,16})$` should work and means "empty"(`^$` is an empty string, nothing between the start and end of it) OR 8-16 word symbols between the start and end of string.